# Create Dynamic Column In Kendo Grid (Javascript)

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to create a kendo grid with dynamic column all the columns will be create on client side.

as an example:

I have written the below code to create a grid :

```
var grid = $("#grid");
        grid.children().remove();
        grid.kendoGrid({
            columns: [{ title: 'One', width: '100px' }, { title: 'Two', width: '100px' }, {title: 'Three', width:'100px'}],
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("")",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        traditional: true,
                        data: {
                            itemTypeId: $("#").val(),
                            where: ["", "", "", "", ""],
                            orderBy: ["", "", ""],
                        },
                    },
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "",
                    total: "",
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 4,
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e.errors);
                }
            },
            pageable: true,
            resizable: true,
            reorderable: true,
        })
    }
```

When i define the column by :

```
columns: [{ title: 'One', width: '100px' }, { title: 'Two', width: '100px' }, {title: 'Three', width:'100px'}],
```

the above code is working fine.

But I want to create all these column in a loop which is not working.

like as : 
I am holding the schema in a javascript variable and then assigning it to the kendo grid.

```
Var columnSchema = "{ title: 'One', width: '100px' },{ title: 'Two', width: '100px' },{ title: 'Two', width: '100px' }";

columns : [columnSchema]
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One slight change to your code and it should work:

```
var columnSchema = [{ title: 'One', width: '100px' },{ title: 'Two', width: '100px' },{ title: 'Three', width: '100px' }];

grid.kendoGrid({
    // .. other properties ..
    columns : columnSchema
});
```

You need to define your columnSchema variable as an array instead of a string (as shown in my example), and it will work.

You could also build the array, e.g.

```
var columnSchema = [];
columnSchema.push({ title: 'One', width: '100px' });
columnSchema.push({ title: 'Two', width: '100px' });
columnSchema.push({ title: 'Three', width: '100px' });
```

You could use `push(..)` inside a loop that reads column information from somewhere else if needed.

As long as this is done before you use the variable to initialise the grid. Once the grid has been created you can't change the columns.

If you need to change columns after the grid has been created you'll need to call the `destroy()` method first, then `kendoGrid(..)` again with the new column spec.